# how to move images from left to right in android?

Tags: android

I'll get images from web.some times i'll get 1,sometimes 2 and
 sometimes 3.i need to move these images from left to right on my
 screen.presently i'm using the following method

```
animation.addFrame(LoadImageFromWebOperations(feed.getItem(i).getImage()), 1000);
animation.addFrame(LoadImageFromWebOperations(feed.getItem(i).getImage1()), 1000);
animation.addFrame(LoadImageFromWebOperations(feed.getItem(i).getImage2()), 1000);
```

When there but when there is only oneor two images then i'm getting
 force close

Comment: Left to write...or left to right?

Comment: Then I have no idea what you are talking about...

Comment: moving image from left to right

Comment: You mean "right," not "write."  There's an English barrier here.  He means "left to right," everyone.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an animation xml file in animator folder under resource

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
```

and  then set animation using

```
   Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this,R.anim.xmlfile);
    TextView txt=new TextView(this);
    txt.setAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Check api demos given in android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy with [Android TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

```
ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);

TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
    animation.setDuration(5000);  // animation duration 
    animation.setRepeatCount(5);  // animation repeat count
    animation.setRepeatMode(2);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
    //animation.setFillAfter(true);      

    img_animation.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation
```

find more details from here [move an image from left to right and right to left in android](http://javasrilankansupport.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-move-an-image-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-in-android.html)